# Struct Undeclared Identifier

Tags: c++

i am beginner in c++ programming, I a have struct Employee: Please see the code,

```
struct Employee
{
    int emp_ID = 0;
    string emp_Name = "";
    string emp_Address = "";
    string emp_Contact_Number = "";
    string em_position = "";
    string dt_emp_started = "";
};
```

and trying to call it inside int main like,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   Employee emp;
   cout<< "Employee ID : " , cin >> emp.emp_ID;
}
```

but it returns this error,

`'Employee' undeclared identifier.`

Did i do it wrong? What should I do to fix it? thanks and regards

Comment: You're not including "employee.h" in "main.cpp".  (And `#include <windows.h>` should be in `"stdafx.h".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line where you are declaring the `Employee` variable, you must have previously defined what an `Employee` is. So, you have to either define the `struct` above in the same file, or if defined in another file, eg `employee.hpp` you should `#include` that file.

If you are just declaring a reference or pointer to that type, or declaring a function which accept or return it, you can forward declare the type (although that seems not your case), as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration) explains

Comment: Sir, but it was in the same file.

Comment: If it is defined above?

Comment: OH! Now I get it, I should create the struct above the main and after the includes and using namespace, isn't that right sir?

Comment: That should work. You may also use a forward declaration if you are going to define it below

Comment: What  do you mean by forward declaration sir?

Comment: Check out this posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c